# How do additional loss terms impact the parameter count in a Deep Neural Network?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, multitask-learning

I've been working on training DNNs for various tasks and recently started incorporating additional loss terms into my models to improve convergence and performance.

I'm curious to know if I need to add parameters (e.g. layers) when I add loss terms encoding ``soft'' constraints or prior knowledge. Can someone provide some references about this?

More practically, can I first search for the best the number of layer and then the best combination of loss term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the loss you have in mind -- the ones that add parameters add parameters and the ones that don't, don't. As an example, you could compute a loss that is $(\hat y - y)^2 + | \hat y - y|$. This has 2 terms, but both terms use the same, single output $\hat y$, so it adds no additional parameters.

Now consider an alternative case where you classify some objects in multiple ways. This could be a binary task ("Is this shape a triangle?") and a categorical task ("Is this shape red or yellow or blue?"). You can construct a loss that adds  binary and multinomial loss together, but you'll need one output to estimate "triangle" and two (or three) outputs to estimate colors. This will add parameters compared to a model which only does exactly one of these tasks.

Comment: Really good point. Do you think that the case when I have a data-fit term and a model-prior (e.g. PDE equation) is similar to color-shape case?

Comment: @Chutlhu Yeah, sounds similar to me. If you've found this answer helpful, please consider up-voting or accepting.